# Is a wiki type question appropriate for the site?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

When I saw the question https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/775/deaths-caused-by-the-doctrine-of-humors I began to think that this might be a useful type of wiki question; although I think this particular one would be a bad example.  In the ParentingSE that I am a member of there are a few questions, one of which is mine [Strategies for preventing Diaper Rash](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/what-are-some-good-strategies-for-preventing-diaper-rash) (so I may be biased here), which have wiki type answers.  It may fit the format there but I was wondering how we might handle questions here?  Some historical questions might fit into this category, where just one answer won't suffice, but many answers might be a good response to a broader historical question on some topic.  Although I think this is rare, and I have one question in mind that might benefit from this sort of format, I was wondering what the thoughts on this were.  It does tend to go against the one-answer with sources rule that has been generally following on the HistorySE, but with judicious use some answers might benefit from this.

Answer (score 2):

It was the typical useless question - there is no chance that somebody who stumbles upon it later learns anything useful from it. So definitely not appropriate on this site. See also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: Agreed, that question was not worth it but I have seen others that were best answered that way.  It was why I asked.